Bootstrap simulations of hierarchically reconciled forecasts?
Q: What exactly are bootstrap simulated forecast paths of hierarchically reconciled forecasts in R's fable package? To my surprise, they're not the result of bootstrap simulating baseline forecasts and reconciling each of those, as I show below.
From Forecasting Principles and Practice, Ch. 11.2
library(fpp3)

tourism_states <- tourism |>
  aggregate_key(State, Trips = sum(Trips))
tourism_states |>
  model(ets = ETS(Trips)) |>
  reconcile(bu = bottom_up(ets)) |>
  forecast()

#> # A fable: 144 x 5 [1Q]
#> # Key:     State, .model [18]
#>    State  .model Quarter         Trips .mean
#>    <chr*> <chr>    <qtr>        <dist> <dbl>
#>  1 ACT    ets    2018 Q1  N(701, 7651)  701.
#>  2 ACT    ets    2018 Q2  N(717, 8032)  717.
#>  3 ACT    ets    2018 Q3  N(734, 8440)  734.
#>  4 ACT    ets    2018 Q4  N(750, 8882)  750.
#>  5 ACT    ets    2019 Q1  N(767, 9368)  767.
#>  6 ACT    ets    2019 Q2  N(784, 9905)  784.
#>  7 ACT    ets    2019 Q3 N(800, 10503)  800.
#>  8 ACT    ets    2019 Q4 N(817, 11171)  817.
#>  9 ACT    bu     2018 Q1  N(701, 7651)  701.
#> 10 ACT    bu     2018 Q2  N(717, 8032)  717.

where, as I expected, the .mean value in row 1 equals that in row 9, row 2 equals that in row 10, and so on. In other words, the baseline forecasts ets at the lowest level of the hierarchy (here, that's State) are the same as the bottom-up reconciled forecasts bu.
But then, the following surprised me.
tourism_states |>
  model(ets = ETS(Trips)) |>
  reconcile(bu = bottom_up(ets)) |>
  forecast(boostrap=TRUE,times=1)

# # A fable: 144 x 5 [1Q]
# # Key:     State, .model [18]
# State  .model Quarter     Trips .mean
# <chr*> <chr>    <qtr>    <dist> <dbl>
# 1 ACT    ets    2018 Q1 sample[1]  650.
# 2 ACT    ets    2018 Q2 sample[1]  671.
# 3 ACT    ets    2018 Q3 sample[1]  519.
# 4 ACT    ets    2018 Q4 sample[1]  631.
# 5 ACT    ets    2019 Q1 sample[1]  824.
# 6 ACT    ets    2019 Q2 sample[1]  643.
# 7 ACT    ets    2019 Q3 sample[1]  647.
# 8 ACT    ets    2019 Q4 sample[1]  810.
# 9 ACT    bu     2018 Q1 sample[1]  744.
# 10 ACT    bu     2018 Q2 sample[1]  568

The bottom-up forecasts are no longer the same as the baseline forecasts. I expected bootstrapping in this context meant that forecast sample paths of the baseline forecasts were constructed and then each of those would be reconciled bottom-up. But that's clearly not happening.
So then, what exactly are these bottom-up forecasts bu in the context of bootstrapping? Are they the result of sampling in-sample fit residuals from the baseline forecasts and applying them to the bottom-up forecast, where one would not expect these sort of bottom-up simulations to equal the baseline simulations.

The reconciled forecasts are as you expect, however the base forecasts of your ets and bu models contain different base bootstrapped samples.
If you set the seed for the bootstrapped samples (obtained from generate()), you will find the expected results.
library(fpp3)

tourism_states <- tourism |>
  aggregate_key(State, Trips = sum(Trips))

tourism_states |>
  model(ets = ETS(Trips)) |>
  reconcile(bu = bottom_up(ets)) |>
  forecast(bootstrap=TRUE,times=1,seed=1)
#> # A fable: 144 x 5 [1Q]
#> # Key:     State, .model [18]
#>    State  .model Quarter     Trips .mean
#>    <chr*> <chr>    <qtr>    <dist> <dbl>
#>  1 ACT    ets    2018 Q1 sample[1]  701.
#>  2 ACT    ets    2018 Q2 sample[1]  799.
#>  3 ACT    ets    2018 Q3 sample[1]  809.
#>  4 ACT    ets    2018 Q4 sample[1]  861.
#>  5 ACT    ets    2019 Q1 sample[1]  891.
#>  6 ACT    ets    2019 Q2 sample[1]  983.
#>  7 ACT    ets    2019 Q3 sample[1]  914.
#>  8 ACT    ets    2019 Q4 sample[1]  814.
#>  9 ACT    bu     2018 Q1 sample[1]  701.
#> 10 ACT    bu     2018 Q2 sample[1]  799.
#> # i 134 more rows

Created on 2024-05-11 with reprex v2.0.2

That works! So setting seed in this way will produce the same bootstrap samples across models bu and ets. Quick follow-up: does this also create the same bootstrap sample (in indices) across State series within a .model? I.e., would setting seed in this way maintain the innovation covariance structure across State series?

I have a longer follow-up question which I just posted as Different output shape of bootstrap-simulated forecasts: bottom-up vs top-down reconciliation. Your solution here with bottom-up is perfect for me. But then, I was surprised to find different behavior for top-down.

Yes, the seed is set repeatedly at the model level so that the same bootstrap sample indices are used across each time series in the data.
